# Flickering background transition in Chrome / Webkit

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web, webkit

I've made a very easy site and I'd like to make a background transition. However when I apply the transition to a `background-size: cover`, the background image flickers on transition, as seen in the fiddle I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/yff98/

The problem lies in:

```
#slideshow {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
transition: 0.5s;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Whenever I remove the `background-size`, the flickering disappears.

I already tried adding the following to the #slideshow:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
```

But that didn't work, unfortunately. Anyone any ideas? (Remember to check in Webkit)

Comment: When the div is in a transition between an image width of 1280 and another of 1200 px, what size do you the expect the background to have ? May be you should make the job easier for the poor div.